# If else in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

The given insert query is very huge in my procedure. All insert queries for given different conditions are very same. how to prepare a loop to avoid giving insert queries each time rather than one time.

```
begin
insert query(..........)
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 12 then
insert query(..........)
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 22 then
insert query(..........)
endif;
end
```

I need procedure like,

```
begin
if dayofmonth(now()) = 2 then
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 12 then
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 22 then
????
insert query(........)
how to end this???
```

could anyone help me?. Thanks advance..

Comment: If the queries are the same, why do you need to loop through anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
begin

if dayofmonth(now()) = 6 then
SET @query="columnnames and values"
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 12 then
SET @query="columnnames and values"
elseif dayofmonth(now()) = 22 then
SET @query="columnnames and values"
endif;

SET @query=concat("insert into", @query)
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1;

end
```